# Calling function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Adding three variables through score function

How can I call my function? Here I want to add all three variables. Why doesn´t it show the output?

```
 def score(x,y,z):
        x == 1
        y == 2
        z == 3
        return (x+y+z)
```

Comment: Ignoring the use of `==` instead of `=`, why would you assign to the parameters inside the function like that?

Answer (score 1):

It is `x = 1...` not `==`, `==` is comparison `=` is assignment.

```
def score():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    return (x+y+z)
```

Then:

```
print(score()) # -> 6
```

If you want to pass the values:

```
def score(x,y,z):
    return (x+y+z)

print(score(1,2,3)) # -> 6
```

If you wanted to test the values passed in were certain numbers you would use `==`:

```
def score(x, y, z):
    if x == 1 and y == 2 and z == 3:
        return x + y + z
```

That tests if `x` is *equal* to 1 and y is *equal* to 2 and z is *equal* to 3

A more logical reason to assign values to x y and z would be to give x,y and z default values:

```
def score(x=1, y=2, z=3):
     return x + y + z
```

So calling `print(score(4))` would output `9` as `x` would be equal to 4 and the default values for `y` and `z` are used.

Comment: thanks for the answer. now if x has multiple values , for example here i have assigned x = 1 but lets say if Iwant to assign x = 5, and x = 4 and i want want to add them in the end to get final score . how i would do it?

Comment: @Bikramjit, you cannot have multiple variables with the same name, once you reassign `x` the old value is lost.

Comment: @ Padraic thanks again for prompt reply. I have a problem to write a function in which many statements are there.Everytime if the statement is correct i need to add 1 else  -1 and in the end i have to print the total score.how can i do it with one variable. hope you understand my question.

Comment: Thanks man, problem solved. i tried in the end I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning values, just checking a boolean.

And, even though you assign x,y,z in your function, make sure you're including arguments when calling it. However, your result will always be 6 no matter what arguments you pass, because you're changing their values in the function.

So, to use scores it should be:

```
def score(x,y,z):
    return (x+y+z)
```

or, if you want a constant one:

```
def score():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    return(x+y+z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define the parameters first:

```
def score(x,y,z):
    return (x+y+z)

print(score(1, 5, 2))
```

> Output: 7

If you want constant scores, you shouldn't even put any parameters in the first place. You used =`=` instead of `=` too.

```
def score():
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    return (x+y+z)

print(score())
```

> Output: 6

Answer (score 1):

In python, there's to use for the `=` character: if you use it alone, it is an assignment:

```
>>> a = 8
>>> print(a)
8
```

The other is a test, which returns a boolean, True or False: we use it to test if a variable equals another:

```
>>> 1 == 2
False
>>> 1 == 1
True
>>> a = 1    # Here, it's an asignment
>>> b = 1
>>> a == b
True
>>> b = 2
>>> a == b
False
```

In your code, you use the test: thus, the variables x, y, and z aren't modified. You must instead write:

def score(x, y, z):
      x = 1
      y = 2
      z = 3
      return (x + y + z)

if you want to assign 1, 2 and 3 to x, y and z. But please note that in this case, the three parameters are useless: this function is simply:

```
def score(x, y, z):
    return (1 + 2 + 3)
```